# How can I download camera Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros users:

I would like to download the pkg of this camera which Gazebo provides us:

[image description http://i57.tinypic.com/jf8414.png](http://i57.tinypic.com/jf8414.png)

So I would like that when I launch a .launch the camera is in the same place and I would like to be able to access topics (for example "camera/link/camera/image" as you can see below on the pic) in the terminal or in RVIZ.
So it is possible to download this camera as pkg? Or to do that in any way?

Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217352/how-can-i-download-camera-gazebo/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can insert models to your world from gazebo model database using the insert tab on the gazebo simulator. When you insert a particular model it will get downloaded locally in your `~/.gazebo/models/package_name`. If you want the camera model to be a part of your world you can follow this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Camera) .

---

Originally posted by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) with karma: 206 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you looking for this? http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_pkgs

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1